# Show a label if the row exists in a SQL database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a text box, a button and a lable which is not visible. We enter something in the text box, then click the button, and if the data exists in the database, the label becomes visible. Here's my code, but when I click on the button, nothing happens:

```
DBConnect MySQLcnn = new DBConnect();
string myString = "SELECT name FROM students WHERE s_id = '" + 123 + "'";
MySQLcnn.PerformSearch(myString);
if(textBox1.text == myString)
{
   confirm.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Theres nothing in the code snippet you posted that triggers on the button click (I'm assuming winforms?) or that sets textBox1.text value. So having to guess, I would guess your textBox1.text value is not the same as myString and your if statement evaluates false. You also should really look into using parameterized input if youre going to have an open text box feed your query.

Comment: Why are you querying the database if you aren't doing anything with the results? You're just looking to see if what the user typed into the text box is the same as the SQL query string, not the results of the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string sql = "SELECT name FROM students WHERE s_id = '" + 123 + "'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        name = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if(textBox1.text == myString)
        {
          confirm.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```